# Detect proxy settings of default web browser

Tags: c#, proxy

MSDN sample

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
WebProxy myProxy=new WebProxy();
// Obtain the 'Proxy' of the  Default browser.  
myProxy=(WebProxy)myWebRequest.Proxy;
```

Doesn't work.
The error I get is: Unable to cast object of type 'WebProxyWrapper' to type 'System.Net.WebProxy'

What options do I have?

Answer (score 10):

`HttpWebRequest.Proxy` returns an `IWebProxy` interface, not `WebProxy`. Change that and it will work.

You can also use [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) or [WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx) to get the proxy details instead of making an `HttpWebRequest` and getting the proxy from that.

Answer (score -3):

To check automatically detect setting, use code:

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);
RegistryKey registry2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Connections", true);
registry2.DeleteValue("DefaultConnectionSettings", false);
registry2.DeleteValue("SavedLegacySettings", false);
```

Comment: This code certainly doesn't check settings, but changes and deletes them.