# .NET proxy detection

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

I am having an issue with .NET detecting the proxy settings configured through internet explorer.

I'm writing a client application that supports proxies, and to test I set up an array of 9 squid servers to support various authentication methods for HTTP and HTTPs. I have a script that updates IE to whichever configuration I choose (which proxy, detection via "Auto", PAC, or hardcode).

I have tried the 3 methods below to detect the IE configuration through .NET. On occassion I notice that .NET picks up the wrong set of proxy servers. IE has the correct settings, and if I browse the web with IE, I can see I am hitting the correct servers via wireshark.

`WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy(destination);`

`GlobalProxySelection.Select.GetProxy(destination);`

`WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`

Here are the following tips I have:

- My script sets a PAC file on a webserver, and updates the configuration in IE, then clears IE's cache
- .NET seems to get "stuck" on a certain proxy configuration, and I have to set another configuration for .NET to realize there was a change. Occasionally it seems to pick some random set of servers (I'm sure they're not random, just a set of servers I used once and are in some cached PAC file or something). As in, I will check the proxy for the destination "https://www.secure.com" and I may have IE configured for and thus expect to get "http://squidserver:18" and instead it will return "http://squidserver:28" (port 18 runs NTLM, 28 runs without authentication). All the squid servers work.
- This does not appear to be an issue on XP, only Vista, 2003, and windows 7.
- Hardcoding the proxy servers in IE ALWAYS works
- Time always solves the issue - if I leave the computer for about 20 or 30 minutes and come back, .NET picks up the correct proxy settings, as if a cached PAC script expired.

Comment: Can't you use UseDefaultProy?

Comment: UseDefaultProxy? Not able to find anything on that online.

Comment: Does this help at all? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023635/detect-proxy-settings-of-default-web-browser-c/1023978#1023978

Comment: Don't know why I blanked on that - Same problem. Question udpated

Comment: Could you give more details on what result you expect, and what result you actually get ?

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, Question updated (some time ago)

Comment: Why don't you check the .NET Framework source code to see what it is actually doing? You can download it from Microsoft here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/Default.aspx You can also debug through the proxy code in Visual Studio to see what it is doing and where it is getting its proxy values from.

Comment: +1 for pushing me to achieve, James. Sorry it's not the +100 :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

.NET uses the "WinHttp Web Proxy Auto Discovery Service" to perform PAC script execution, and probably caches the results. Simply stopping and restarting this service does the trick. The following command line does this for me.

```
NET STOP WinHttpAutoProxySvc
NET START WinHttpAutoProxySvc
```

http://wiki.blackviper.com/wiki/WinHTTP_Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Service

I found this by following James Kovacs' suggestion of attaching the debugger. I had already reflected through the code and made a failed attempt to attach a debugger before I ever posted the question, but could not decipher exactly what was happening. Running out of options, I tried debugging again, and after several hours found the following comment in _AutoPWebProxyScriptEngine.cs on line 76 that led me to this discovery

```
        // In Win2003 winhttp added a Windows Service handling the auto-proxy discovery. In XP using winhttp
        // APIs will load, compile and execute the wpad file in-process. This will also load COM, since 
        // WinHttp requires COM to compile the file. For these reasons, we don't use WinHttp on XP, but
        // only on newer OS versions where the "WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service" exists.
```

Comment: The link is dead now.  I found this link which looks like the same information, but I'm not going to edit into the question since I'm not 100% sure if this really is the same thing.  http://www.blackviper.com/windows-services/winhttp-web-proxy-auto-discovery-service/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I succeded getting/setting the proxy setting in registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]   
"ProxyServer"="&lt;your proxy IP address&gt;:8080"
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyOverride"="&lt;local&gt;"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Radu. Unfortunately I'm only looking to detect proxy settings, not set them, and the reg settings around this key don't help if IE is set to auto detect proxy. And I'd rather not write my own Auto Proxy Detector.